# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') - @vue/test-utils

Tags: vue-composition-api, vue-test-utils, babel-jest

when trying to test Single-File Components in vue environment, an error occurs.

this is my bean with registration logic:

`RegistrationComponents.vue`

```
<template>
  <form class="form" v-on:submit="userRegistration">

      <div class="input-wrapper mb-4">
        <p class="uppercase text-raleway-13">Email Address</p>
        <input
          maxlength="255"
          @input="ch"
          type="email"
          name="email"
          class="input email_address"
          autocapitalize="off"
          :class="{ 'bg-status-red-border': errorEmail[0] }"
        />
        <p class="text text-raleway-13 error pointer t-danger mt-2">
          {{ errorEmail[0] }}
        </p>
      </div>


  </form>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { loginValidation } from "../../utils/validation/login";
import { RegistrationType, RegistrationForm } from "./type";
import PasswordComponent from "../password/passwordComponent.vue";

 --- and more ts logic ---

</script>
```

this is my sample test that throws an error:

`registration.spec.ts`

```
import RegistrationComponents from "../../src/components/registration/RegistrationComponents.vue";
import { expect, test } from "@jest/globals";
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils";

test("1. The user with the data exists in the system. my@mail.com", () => {
  const wrapper = mount(RegistrationComponents, {
    global: {
      mocks: {
        $tc: (msg: string) => msg,
      },
    },
  });
  const emailInput = wrapper.find<HTMLInputElement>(".email_address");

  emailInput.setValue("my@mail.com");

  expect(emailInput.element.value).toBe("my@mail.com");
});
```

error that occurs after running the test:

```
Test suite failed to run                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
      at Proxy.render (src/components/registration/RegistrationComponents.vue:291:110)
      at renderComponentRoot (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:897:44)
      at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5555:57)
      at ReactiveEffect.run (node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.cjs.js:191:25)
      at instance.update (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5669:56)
      at setupRenderEffect (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5683:9)
      at mountComponent (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5465:9)
      at processComponent (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5423:17)
      at patch (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5027:21)
      at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5562:21)
      at ReactiveEffect.run (node_modules/@vue/reactivity/dist/reactivity.cjs.js:191:25)
      at instance.update (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5669:56)
      at setupRenderEffect (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5683:9)
      at mountComponent (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5465:9)
      at processComponent (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5423:17)
      at patch (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:5027:21)
      at render (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:6183:13)
      at mount (node_modules/@vue/runtime-core/dist/runtime-core.cjs.js:4417:25)
      at Object.app.mount (node_modules/@vue/runtime-dom/dist/runtime-dom.cjs.js:1523:23)
      at mount (node_modules/@vue/test-utils/dist/vue-test-utils.cjs.js:8291:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/registration.spec.ts:6:24)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)
```

as I was able to find out, the error occurs due to the fact that the template is not generated specifically in this example. Whereas it works when generated in empty components. That is, in those in which there are no scripts

additional information, compilation and running of the project proceeds normally